# Problem with the DNS settings for our new company mailserver

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email, nameserver

We are a small business with several branches around our country, trying to improve intra-office communications.

In order to host a mail server at our head office we have upgraded our Business Broadband plan to a Static IP with Port 25 open, purchased two domain names (one for email and another for the public facing website) and set up a high end PC with a router.

Port 80 and 25 have been forwarded successfully. But we have a problem with the DNS settings of the domain.

We would like to set up the mail server using single static IP but the nameserver settings in our ISP's cpanel require two nameservers - how should we proceed?

update :

as one of my frined 'flaflamme' suggested for free dns service provider (http://zonomi.com) and now for my domain :getdatxxx.in( x marked for privacy ) and my staic ip 121.243.xxx.xx

and dns settings goes like this is this sufficient ?

IP Addresses (A)
Domain      IP Address
getdatacards.in points to   121.243.xxx.xx
getdatxxx.in    points to   121.243.xxx.xx

Mail Servers (MX)
Mail Server Handles Email For   Order
getdatxxx.in    getdatxxx.in    0

Name Servers (NS)

Name Server     Domain
ns1.zonomi.com  handles DNS for getdatxxx.in
ns2.zonomi.com  handles DNS for getdatxxx.in
Zone Configuration (SOA)
Primary Name Server ns1.zonomi.com

DNS Host Master soacontact.zonomi.com

Secondary Refresh   3 hours
Secondary Retry 1 hour
Secondary Expire    1 week
Default Record Cache Time   1 hour

please tell me whether this works for me  and do i need to update this dns1 & 2 in  my domain hosted control panel ??

Comment: What other StackExchange site did you copy this from? Did you leave a copy there, too? Or is this the only one?

Comment: actually i questioned this in other stack exchange. site i.e IT Security.stackexchange.com  so instead of typing every thing same once again i copied question . that's all

Comment: Can you tell us what mail server product you're going to use?

Comment: I've flagged it for closing there as I think this is a better place for it (maybe not the best place though).

Comment: @toomanyairmiles  hmaillserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the DNS settings, sure, you will need to add two NS servers, if you don't own any nameservers , I suggest you to try namecheap freedns service, they will host your dns settings and provide you with a control panel, then, you can add your records.

```
@domain.com   A (IP ADDRESS OF WEB SERVER)
www           A (IP ADDRESS OF WEB SERVER)
@            MX (IP ADDRESS OF YOUR NEW MACHINE)
```

Finally, if you are not aware of the dns settings and optimum/antispam configuration of a mail server, i suggest you to use Google Apps for Domain which is free under a certain volume of mail and users.  Because fighting spam could lead you to serious headaches and false positives.

Comment: google apps already using for official domain . so we need to host our own mail server .  we have static ip , and planning to use hmailserver has mail server software on windows .. is this enough to use along with free dns at namecheap free service .

Comment: Yes it is sufficient using this service, you don't need to own nameservers and you can add the given configuration in my answer.

Comment: please got to question and i update the question with settings i got from the free dsn service provider for my static ip and domain .. suggest me to move further .. should i use these tow dsn1 & 2 server details where my Domian(getdataxx.com) is hosted

Comment: When you will use namecheap freedns service (http://www.namecheap.com/products/freedns.aspx) you will have NAMECHEAP dns servers for nameservers. However, you have to add thoses namecheap dns servers IPs to your domain registrar for freedns to work, Just follow the process on the namecheap website, you will see everything before "making the switch". This won't affect anything until you change the nameservers at your domain registrars.

Comment: thankyou  we will proceed using this settings but do you think hmailserver software is enough for us or should we go for a paid software we are planning use this server only on office hours and rest of the time this server will be down .

Comment: I cannot help you on windows servers. Also, please stick to the original question and answers. If you need to, create a new question and other members will be pleased to answer your questions. Best regards